# How to stop/ inturrupt current loop (sequence) to run new data (sequence)?

Tags: c++, arduino

Incoming strings, such as "121" or "434" are sent to `softSerial1`. I am trying to make the program so that if a new string is received, the sequence of events will stop in the middle and re-start looping the new sequence. For example, say "121" is sent. The sequence is gone through 1, then 2--but say "434" is suddenly received. How to get the 121 sequence to immediately stop (not finish the complete sequence) and start running the "434" sequence?

Here is one of many attempts:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial softSerial1(10, 11); // RX, TX

bool once1 = false, latch1 = false, latch2 = false, newData = false, halfway = false, originStop = false;

volatile int countSequence = 1;
volatile int x_2initial = 0;

byte leng = 0;
int locus = 0;
String sequence = "";
char str2[60];
char str3[60];



//----------------------------once---------------------------- 
void setup()
{
  softSerial1.begin(9600); // Receive data on pin 8
  Serial.begin(19200);
  delay(500); // Necessary for clean serial monitor
}



//----------------------------LOOP---------------------------- 
void loop()
{
  receiveEvent();
}

void receiveEvent()
{
  while(newData == false)
  {
    if(softSerial1.available())
    {
      sequence = softSerial1.readStringUntil('\n');
      
      checkNewString(); // <-----
      
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Sequence: ");
      Serial.print(sequence);
      Serial.println();
      
      leng = sequence.length();
      char receivedChars[60];
      sequence.toCharArray(receivedChars, leng+1);
      if(sequence != "")
        strcpy(str2, receivedChars);
      
      Serial.print("str2: ");
      Serial.print(str2);
      Serial.println();            
    }
    
    for(int index = 0; index < leng; index ++)
    {
      checkNewString();
      Serial.print("str2, movements: ");
      Serial.print(str2[index]);
      Serial.println();
      movement(str2[index]);
    }    
  }
  checkNewString();
  newData = false;
  Serial.println("--- --- --- Exit loop //////");
  delay(2000);
}



void checkNewString()
{
  if (str2 != "" && strcmp(str2, str3) != 0) 
  {                                 // ^ If they're different
    if(latch1 == false)
    {
      strcpy(str3, str2);             // make them the same
      latch1 = true;
      Serial.println("NEW if DATA");
    }
    else
    {
      strcpy(str3, str2);
      newData = true;
      Serial.println("NEW else DATA");
    }
      
    Serial.print("-str2: ");
    Serial.print(str2);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("-str3: ");
    Serial.print(str3);
    Serial.println();          
  }
}





void movement(char locusChoice)
{
  Serial.print("Enter function, ");
  switch(locusChoice)
  {
      
    case '1':
      Serial.print("forward...");
      Serial.println();
      forward();
      latch2 = false;
      break;
      
    case '2':
      Serial.print("backward...");
      Serial.println();    
      backward();
      latch2 = false;
      break;
      
  }      
}



// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 



void forward()
{
  checkNewString();
  while(newData == false && latch2 == false)
  {
    checkNewString();
    
    Serial.println("Forward");
    delay(5000);
    
    latch2 = true;
  }  

}

  
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

void backward()
{
  checkNewString();
  while(newData == false && latch2 == false)
  {
    checkNewString();
    
    Serial.println("Backward");
    delay(5000);

    latch2 = true;
  }
}
```

This prints:

> ```
> Sequence: 121
> str2: 121
> NEW if DATA
> -str2: 121
> -str3: 121
> str2, movements: 1
> Enter function, forward...
> Forward
> str2, movements: 2
> Enter function, backward...
> Backward
> str2, movements: 1
> Enter function, forward...
> Forward
>
> Sequence: 434
> str2: 434
> NEW else DATA
> -str2: 434
> -str3: 434
> str2, movements: 4
> Enter function, str2, movements: 3
> Enter function, str2, movements: 4
> Enter function, --- --- --- Exit loop //////
> --- --- --- Exit loop //////
> --- --- --- Exit loop //////
> --- --- --- Exit loop //////
> ```

So there are two issues. The first is how to get the new data interrupt to work. The second is to continue looping the sequence.

Comment: Avoid using loops.  Use the loop() function as your main loop, and use if() to activate parts of the code, this will give your app the ability to handle several activities simultaneously.